# SafeERC20: low-level call failed safeTransferFrom

Tags: erc-20, bridge

I`m developing a token bridge based on the omnibridge contracts here https://github.com/omni/omnibridge https://github.com/omni/tokenbridge

When calling relayTokens from my dapp Im getting JSON RPC error and "Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit" errors.

So I tried manually sent a failing transaction and it fails at "SafeERC20: low-level call failed". I have tried calling with different tokens and addresses, but im not sure why it would be failing here?

```
library SafeERC20 {
using SafeMath for uint256;
using Address for address;

function safeTransfer(IERC20 token, address to, uint256 value) internal {
    _callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transfer.selector, to, value));
}

function safeTransferFrom(IERC20 token, address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
    _callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transferFrom.selector, from, to, value));
}

/**
 * @dev Imitates a Solidity high-level call (i.e. a regular function call to a contract), relaxing the requirement
 * on the return value: the return value is optional (but if data is returned, it must not be false).
 * @param token The token targeted by the call.
 * @param data The call data (encoded using abi.encode or one of its variants).
 */
function _callOptionalReturn(IERC20 token, bytes memory data) private {
    // We need to perform a low level call here, to bypass Solidity's return data size checking mechanism, since
    // we're implementing it ourselves. We use {Address.functionCall} to perform this call, which verifies that
    // the target address contains contract code and also asserts for success in the low-level call.

    bytes memory returndata = address(token).functionCall(data, "SafeERC20: low-level call failed");
    if (returndata.length > 0) { // Return data is optional
        // solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(abi.decode(returndata, (bool)), "SafeERC20: ERC20 operation did not succeed");
    }
}
```

}

And these are the relay token functions I am calling

```
/**
 * @dev Initiate the bridge operation for some amount of tokens from msg.sender.
 * The user should first call Approve method of the ERC677 token.
 * @param token bridged token contract address.
 * @param _receiver address that will receive the native tokens on the other network.
 * @param _value amount of tokens to be transferred to the other network.
 */
function relayTokens(
    IERC677 token,
    address _receiver,
    uint256 _value
) external {
    _relayTokens(token, _receiver, _value, new bytes(0));
}

/**
 * @dev Validates that the token amount is inside the limits, calls transferFrom to transfer the tokens to the contract
 * and invokes the method to burn/lock the tokens and unlock/mint the tokens on the other network.
 * The user should first call Approve method of the ERC677 token.
 * @param token bridge token contract address.
 * @param _receiver address that will receive the native tokens on the other network.
 * @param _value amount of tokens to be transferred to the other network.
 * @param _data additional transfer data to be used on the other side.
 */
function _relayTokens(
    IERC677 token,
    address _receiver,
    uint256 _value,
    bytes memory _data
) internal {
    // This lock is to prevent calling passMessage twice if a ERC677 token is used.
    // When transferFrom is called, after the transfer, the ERC677 token will call onTokenTransfer from this contract
    // which will call passMessage.
    require(!lock());

    uint256 balanceBefore = token.balanceOf(address(this));
    setLock(true);
    token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _value);
    setLock(false);
    uint256 balanceDiff = token.balanceOf(address(this)).sub(balanceBefore);
    require(balanceDiff <= _value);
    bridgeSpecificActionsOnTokenTransfer(address(token), msg.sender, _receiver, balanceDiff, _data);
}
```

This is my web3 code. The token address seems valid. I am checking the allowance and it seems fine. The amount is less or same as the allowance

```
  const abi = ['function relayTokens(address, address, uint256)'];
  const mediatorContract = new Contract(mediator, abi, signer);

  const abi2 = ['function allowance(address, address) view returns (uint256)'];
  const tokenContract = new Contract(token.address, abi2, signer);
  const allowance = await tokenContract.allowance(receiver, mediator);
  console.log("ALLOWANCE", allowance.toString())
  return mediatorContract.relayTokens(token.address, receiver, amount);
```